# Batch upload and accurate progress with AFNetworking

Tags: ios, asihttprequest, afnetworking

I used to upload multiple images with enqueued requests (ASINetworkQueues).

It had the ability to show accurate progress, i.e. show how many bytes have been sent over all bytes within the queue (http://allseeing-i.com/ASIHTTPRequest/How-to-use#accurate_progress_vs_simple_progress).

Can I do the same without too much effort with AFNetworking?

Comment: I am now using NSProgress.